# Android : Nearest match query from SQLite DB if input string value is bigger than any of the DB values?

Tags: android, sql

I have DB entries:
James
Andy
Bob
David

For input string "Bobby" i want to return the 'Bob' row.
OR for input string "Candy" i want to return 'Andy' row.

I am using Android cursors but can also run the raw query.

Comment: What do you mean by "nearest match"? If the input is "andy", and the database has "candy" and "randy", which is the nearest of those?

Comment: if the input is subset of the entries in DB, i can get both rows using like query. But the problem is when input is bigger then the entries in DB.

Comment: i do not want to go through each row of DB and compare string values.So if the input string is 'Candy', can i get 'andy' from the DB using any kind of query.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like this:

```
SELECT name
FROM names
WHERE name LIKE '%andy%'
OR 'andy' LIKE ('%' || name || '%')
ORDER BY abs(length('andy') - length(name)), name
LIMIT 1
```

It will select the shortest match containing the string "andy" or the longest match that is contained within "andy", using alphabetical order as a tiebreaker. To get *all* rows remove the LIMIT clause.